# A passage in the newman proof of the prime number theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

In the proof of the statement that

$\theta(x) \sim x$

based on the fact that $\int_1^\infty { \frac{\theta(x) - x}{x^2}dx } < \infty$

We assume that for some $\lambda > 1$ there are arbitrarily large x with $\theta(x) \geq \lambda x$
and since $\theta(x)$ is non-decreasing, we have

$\int_x^{\lambda x} { \frac{\theta(t) - t}{t^2}dt } \leq \int_x^{\lambda x} { \frac{\lambda x- t}{t^2}dt } = \int_1^{\lambda} { \frac{\lambda - t}{t^2}dt }$

and we have a contradiction.

my question is:
why in the last equality we choose arbitrarily x = 1?
or where does the last equality comes from?
thank you

Comment: Love it: I had the *exact* same question last month when I read that section.

Comment: Newman's short proof, Zagier, p.707. Your inequality should be $\int \frac{\theta(t)-t}{t^2}dt \geq...$ Might be confusing to someone who didn't have the paper.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $t\leftarrow xt$, $dt\leftarrow xdt$ and voila.

Comment: oh my gosh! that's true!